# Install PANDAS on Mac, big issue

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pandas, pip

I lot of people had asked this question, but I can't find an answer that can help me overcome my problems installing PANDAS on my Mac.

I've tried several procedures previously suggested, but they don't work. This is the error I'm getting.

```
Pablos-MacBook-Pro:pastudilloe$ sudo pip install pandas
```

The directory '/Users/pastudilloe/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

```
The directory '/Users/pastudilloe/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pandas
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/9a/f571a032f5f2bf5b8a5d63ce079428c5423299853ed2d8d96626f441801d/pandas-0.23.3-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (14.6MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 14.6MB 83kB/s 
Collecting numpy>=1.9.0 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/bf/e36756c562f7386be78c6942f0a8a647ee4eb374cdf219bece7054832b14/numpy-1.15.0-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (24.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 24.5MB 49kB/s 
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/f5/af2b09c957ace60dcfac112b669c45c8c97e32f94aa8b56da4c6d1682825/python_dateutil-2.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (211kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 215kB 640kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Users/pastudilloe/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
Installing collected packages: numpy, python-dateutil, pandas
  Found existing installation: numpy 1.8.0rc1
    DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (numpy) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
    Uninstalling numpy-1.8.0rc1:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 302, in move
    copy2(src, real_dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 131, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 103, in copystat
    os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags)
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-62NbGp-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy-1.8.0rc1-py2.7.egg-info'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: you don't want to use `sudo` to install things via `pip`. do `pip install pandas --user` instead. better yet, use conda.

Comment: what's '--user' for? @PaulH

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the error report? `You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.` or is there a reason you are using an old pip?

Comment: `pip install --help` explains it better than I could

Answer (score 1):

uninstall numpy and then try again:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ipython jupyter code,

Add below lines

```
!pip install pandas

!pip install numpy
```

It will be installed during runtime if it is not installed.